# Laravel get data from two tables connected with many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relational-database

Guys I have 2 tables first is **users** second is **notes**:

I am connecting both tables with **Many to many relationship**

> users, notes and user_note tables

[image: See the 3 tables image]

Now I am trying to get logged in user notes where I have logged in user id by `Auth::user() -> id` also I am trying to get **all the other users** that can see the same note.

> For example

**user_id=1** can see **note_id=2** also **user_id=2** can see **note_id=2**.

So **note_id=2** have **2 users**.

> Problem:

I want eloquent that get me all the logged in user's notes and other users that share the same note.

I have tried `whereHas` but I couldn't get what I need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain what the problem is as precisely as possible, if you need help, visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Right now we could implement a random number generator and it would be a valid answer :)

Comment: @Loek thank you.. I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::user();
$notes = $loggedInUser->notes()->with('users')->get();
```

Comment: Yea this will get logged in used notes.. But how I get all the other users that share the same note with the logged in user?

Comment: It will give the notes along with all users that share same note. Try it on `php artisan tinker`. First type: `$user = App\User::first();` then `$user->notes()->with('users')->get()` and check the result for yourself

Comment: If i tried `dd($notes[0] -> title);` it will get me all the logged in user notes and this is perfect but it doesn't get information about the other users which share the same notes.

Comment: Try it in tinker as I suggested. I think for a dd it should be `$notes[0]->users`

Comment: ohhh I am very sorry.. you are totally right! that is awesome! thanks a lot :D :D